# Change Backups (Déjà Dup) encryption password

Tags: password, backup, deja-dup

## Issue:

Déjà Dup doesn't work recognize my password.

I think I just have forgotten it but I don't know how to change the password.

## What I would like to do:

I would like to change the encryption password of Déjà Dup.

I don't care much of the backups I have but if I could change the password even for the price of saying goodbye to my old backups, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start a new backup "chain", so create a new folder on your backup device and tell Deja-Dup to backup into that. It will start from scratch including asking you about the password.

If there is a way to recover the password for the old backups, I do not know it.

Comment: That's all I need to know :) Thanks!
But then, if I want to stop the old backup chain, then, I'll just need to delete the old backup folder or do I need to tell something to Déjà-Dup?

Comment: Once you start a new chain in a new location, I don't believe it will ever go back and reference the old one, unless you specifically point to it on the "storage location" page.